# Array of object

Tags: java, arrays

I need your help to answer this question. I tried to answer it but I cannot.

Question:

1. Design a class Student that contains:

   - An integer data field named ID representing the ID of the student.
   - A String data field named Name representing the name of the student.
   - A double data field named GPA representing the GPA of the student.
   - An integer data field named pass representing the number of passing students.
   - An integer data field named fail representing the number of fails students.
   - A constructor that creates a Student with the specified ID and Name and GPA.
   - A method named printInfo() that take array of object as parameter and print all students details and count how many students pass and how many fails.
     (Note : pass students must score GPA greater than or equal 2)
   - Fails student score GPA less than 2.
   - The accessor and mutator methods for all data fields.
2. Write a test program that:

   - Creates an Array of object named List.
   - Adds any number of students in the List array, by asking the user, how many student you want to enter.
   - Displays the final result for all students.

Help me please. This is my first question

---

This is my answer, but it has an error. Therefore I cannot complete.

package project;

public class Student {

```
private int ID;
private String Name;
private double GPA ;
private int pass;
private int fail;
public Student(int ID, String Name, double GPA) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.GPA = GPA;
}

public String printInfo(){
}

public int getID() {
    return ID;   
}

 public void setID(int ID) {
     this.ID = ID;
 }

 public String getName() {
     return Name;   
    }

 public void setName(String Name) {
     this.Name = Name;
     }

 public double getGPA() {
     return GPA;   
    }

 public void setGPA(double GPA) {
     this.GPA = GPA;
     }

 public int getpass() {
        return pass;   
    }

 public void setpass(int pass) {
         this.pass = pass;
     }

 public int getfail() {
        return fail;   
    }

 public void setfail(int fail) {
         this.fail = fail;
     }
 public int getnum() {
        return num;   
    }

 public void setnum(int num) {
         this.num = num;
     }
```

}

Comment: It smells like a homework to me ;)

Comment: And what is the question? If it is "Can you do it to me?" - the answer is "no".

Comment: Do your own homework - read the chapters you're supposed to and pay attention in class.

Comment: I hope your next question is better.  Please study your text and do your own homework.

Comment: That's not a question. That's a copy-pasted homework assignment.

Comment: This is my answer, but it has some mistakes. Therefore I cannot complete.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Student {
    int ID;
    String Name;
    double GPA;
    ...
```

The professor practically wrote it for you.